# Group vs individual data: how to correct standard errors?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I have a set of 5 variables: Y is a response, and X1, X2, x3, and X4 are the predictors. There are 3,000 observations, and I fit a regression model in R:

fit <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2 +X3 + x4, data = mydata)

The problem is that my data relate to 3,000 small units (parishes) nested in 40 larger units (counties), and Y, X1, and X2 are measured at the parish level, whilst X3 and X4 are only available at a county level. I am concerned that the lm function will underestimate the standard errors for the coefficients for the last two variables. Is there a way to correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mixed models! Something like

```r
library(lmerTest)  ## so you can get p-values on fixed effects
fit <- lmer(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3 + X4 + (1 + X1 + X2 | county), data = mydata)
```

The random-effect term allows the intercept, as well as the parish-level effect of `X1` and `X2`, to vary across counties.

The logic here is that the fixed effects `X1 + x2 + X3 + X4` specify that the model should allow these variables to affect the response at the *population level* (i.e., overall), while the random effects allow for the intercepts and the effects of `X1` and `X2` to vary across counties.  The general rules are that (1) we can include any variable in a random-effects term that varies *within* the levels of the grouping variables (i.e., since `X1` and `X2` vary at the parish level, we can estimate the variance of their effects across counties; since `X3` and `X4` vary only between and not within counties, we *cannot* estimate the variation of their effects across counties) and (2) in general, because the random effects are zero-centered, we should usually include a fixed effect corresponding to each random-effects term.

For what it's worth you can use the `equatiomatic` package to extract LaTeX-formatted model specifications, see the [vignette](http://127.0.0.1:24529/library/equatiomatic/doc/lme4-lmer.html).

Comment: That's great, thank you! I appreciate the logic but can't quite understand syntaxis. In my example, X3 and X4 are measured at level 1, i.e. parish. Should not the formula look like: fit <- lmer(Y ~ X1 + X2 + (1 + X3 + X4 | county), data = mydata)?

Comment: Ok, I understand it now, thanks! Am I right to assume that 'county' refers to the county identifier, which is the same for all parishes in this county? And sorry, one more question. If a variable is endogenous, in OLS I use IV to deal with the bias. Can endogeneity affect mixed models in the same way?

Comment: yes, `county` is the county identifier.  I don't come from an econometric background, so I'm not very familiar with issues of endogeneity/bias/etc. See e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34642/difference-between-panel-data-mixed-model , hopefully helpful ... ?

Comment: Thanks! I fitted my model and got and output of 2 parts, random and fixed effects. Fixed effects are similar to the output of OLS model, and the coefficients for variables entered at a county level are still significant. The variance at the county level is very small, e.g.  7.691e-07 with sd of 0.000877 for one coefficient. This indicates that most variability occurs at the parish level. This is fine, but how does the algorithm know about the variability of county-level variables at a parish level? This is magic! Alternatively, do I misinterpret the results?